# Can't create procedure and function in sql plus oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper

Can't create any procedure/function in pl/sql. Always getting procedure created with compilation error. Last try with following code

```
SQL>  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORT(NAME VARCHAR2, VERSION VARCHAR2,
  2     STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE) AS 
  3   BEGIN 
  4   END REPORT;
  5   /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error procedure report;
Errors for PROCEDURE REPORT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/2      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
         following:
         begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
         raise return select update while with <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
         close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
         savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
```

function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETEMPSALARY (EMPNUMBER IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
IS
DECLARE
EMPSALARY INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT SAL INTO EMPSALARY FROM EMP WHERE EMP.EMPNO = EMPNUMBER;
RETURN EMPSALARY;
END GETEMPSALARY;
/
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: by the way - your procedure IS being created. It just can't be executed until you fix the error(s).

Comment: can you figure out where the error? found the error in procedure but what about the function

Comment: There is no requirement to code in uppercase. Also http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079

Comment: take out the DECLARE in your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure has no statements.  At least put a 
NULL statement in there to get it to compile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORT(NAME VARCHAR2, VERSION VARCHAR2,
      STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE) AS 
BEGIN 
  NULL;
END REPORT;
```

Comment: what about the function

Comment: Well, the function wasn't there when I answer the question about the procedure.  Update the question to show what errors the function is giving you please.

Comment: yeah.. can you help?

Comment: You don't need the DECLARE keyword, but in the future you should post what the error is!

Comment: Thanks alot.. works perfectly.. as beginner great help from your side.. once again thanks with plus vote..